# WPF Treeview complex hierarchy

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I use MVVM pattern in my app. I have these (simplified version) VM classes :

```
public class MainModule_VM
{
    ...

    public ObservableCollection<Module2601_VM> ListModules{...}

    ...
}

public class Module2601_VM
{
    ...

    public string GatewayName {...}
    public string FirmwareVersion{...}
    public string IPAddress{...}
    public string NbIoms{...}
    public ObservableCollection<Module2610_VM> ListModules{...}
    public ObservableCollection<ComPort_VM> ListCOM{...}

    ...
}

public class Module2610_VM
{
    ...

    public string ModuleName{...}

    ...
}

public class ComPort_VM
{
    ...

    public string ComPortName{...}

    ...
}
```

So, one Module2601_VM contains several properties, and a list of Module2610_VM and ComPort_VM objects.

I have one list of Module2601_VM objects in the MainModule_VM class.

I want to bind this collection of Module2601 and it's sub-items in a Treeview, with this hierarchy:

Gateways :

- Gateway #0

  - IP
  - Firmware
  - NbIoms
  - ListModules

    - Module #0
    - Module #1
    - ...
  - ListCOM

    - COM #1
    - ...

My problem is, I get the hierarchy OK, but cannot select sub-items. It takes any gateway item and all it's children as one big item. I know it is because of my itemTemplate, but I fail to solve this problem.
Here is the xaml (DataContext set in code-behind):

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1" >
    <TreeViewItem Header="Gateways" ItemsSource="{Binding ListMM}">
        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding GatewayName, Mode=OneWay}" IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=Gateway.IPAddress, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=Gateway.FirmwareVersion, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=Gateway.NumberIoms, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="MIOs" ItemsSource="{Binding ListModules, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModuleName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="COM" ItemsSource="{Binding ListCOM, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PortCom.ComP, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>      
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeViewItem>                   
</TreeView>
```

With this I cannot select sub-items, it looks like this:
[picture](https://vgb0ra.dm2301.livefilestore.com/y2pgZoGO5u1P2ogz3taN1hzpo7yoXyp5bphX5X97doUR8I0VrQRrx0vrv4vKkMiajuwK4hW2x-VbA3NaPtaDsCXM1ownjIV3qKuAyUTs8t1-0wCXpyCFYFwG2fu_hWDnq2oQ8BdRvMaNZz95e3K-lcTfQ/selectionPb.JPG?psid=1)

Now with the following sample, where I only have one Module2601_VM item in my treeView, it's all fine and I can select individual items:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView2">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Gateways">
        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding GatewayName, Mode=OneWay}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=IPAddress, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=FirmwareVersion, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=NumberIoms, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="MIOs" ItemsSource="{Binding ListModules, Mode=OneWay}">
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModuleName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="COM" ItemsSource="{Binding ListCOM, Mode=OneWay}">
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ComPortName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

How can I have my treeview to be like treeView1 but with treeView2 selection functionnality? 
HierarchicalDataTemplate doesn't work here because child items are of different type.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve the TreeView rappresentation that you describe, in my opinion you should use the "implicit" [DataTemplate mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) and the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Regarding the first point I would create a couple of classes to have a "simple" type for your observable collections:

```
public class Module2610_VMCollection : ObservableCollection<Module2610_VM>
{
}

public class ComPort_VMCollection : ObservableCollection<ComPort_VM>
{
}
```

then Module2601_VM class will become:

```
public class Module2601_VM
{
    /* ... */

    public string GatewayName {get; set;}
    public string FirmwareVersion { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string NbIoms { get; set; }
    public Module2610_VMCollection ListModules { get; set; }
    public ComPort_VMCollection ListCOM { get; set; }

    /* ... */
}
```

Indeed your ViewModel does not reflect the structure you want to show in your UI, so I guess you need a class to "describe" the children of your Module2601_VM. Something like that:

```
public class Module2601_VMChildrenDescriptor : IEnumerator, IEnumerable
{
    private readonly Module2601_VM module2601_VM;
    private int i = -1;

    public Module2601_VMChildrenDescriptor(Module2601_VM module2601_VM)
    {
        this.module2601_VM = module2601_VM;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    return module2601_VM.GatewayName;
                case 1:
                    return module2601_VM.FirmwareVersion;
                case 2:
                    return module2601_VM.IPAddress;
                case 3:
                    return module2601_VM.NbIoms;
                case 4:
                    return module2601_VM.ListModules;
                case 5:
                    return module2601_VM.ListCOM;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return ++i < 6;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        i = -1;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

So the complete view model will be:

```
public class Module2601_VM
{
    private Module2601_VMChildrenDescriptor module2601_VMChildrenDescriptor;
    public Module2601_VM()
    {
        module2601_VMChildrenDescriptor = new Module2601_VMChildrenDescriptor(this);
        ListModules = new Module2610_VMCollection();
        ListCOM = new ComPort_VMCollection();
    }

    public string GatewayName {get; set;}
    public string FirmwareVersion { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string NbIoms { get; set; }
    public Module2610_VMCollection ListModules { get; set; }
    public ComPort_VMCollection ListCOM { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable Children
    {
        get
        {
            return module2601_VMChildrenDescriptor;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need just to declare the DataTemplates in your XAML as resources of the TreeView control:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListModules}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Module2601_VM}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=OneWay}">
            <TextBlock Text="Module2601_VM" Margin="1" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Margin="1" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Module2610_VM}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModuleName, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="1" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Module2610_VMCollection}" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
            <TextBlock Text="ListModules" Margin="1" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ComPort_VM}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ComPortName, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="1" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ComPort_VMCollection}" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
            <TextBlock Text="ComPort_VM" Margin="1" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Now each node of the TreeView is selectable.
I hope it helps.